# How to strip all HTML tags from a string except tags contained inside backticks?

Tags: php

I'm using PHP's `strip_tags()` function to strip tags from a string. For example:

```
$text = strip_tags( $text );
```

My aim is to strip all tags unless the tags happen to be contained inside backticks. If tags are contained inside backticks, I don't want to strip them.

My first thought was to try using the second parameter of `strip_tags()`. This will let me specify allowable tags which are not to be removed. For example, `strip_tags( $text, '<strong>')`. However, this doesn't quite do what I'm looking for.

How can I strip all HTML tags from a string **except** tags that happen to be contained inside backticks?

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: You could do something like, match everything between backticks, replace their contents with the match index, striptags, replace markers with old content.

Comment: I don't think strip_tags is going to work for you. You'll probably need to do a preg_replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To back my comment with an answer, something like:

```
function strip($input)
{
    preg_match_all('/`([^`]+)`/', $input, $retain);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($retain[0]); $i++)
    {
        // Replace HTML wrapped in backticks with match index.
        $input = str_replace($retain[0][$i], "{{$i}}", $input);
    }

    // Strip tags.
    $input = strip_tags($input);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($retain[0]); $i++)
    {
        // Replace previous replacements with relevant data.
        $replace = $retain[1][$i];

        // Do some stuff with $replace here - maybe check that it's a tag
        // you're comfortable with else use htmlspecialchars(), etc.
        // ...

        $input = str_replace("{{$i}}", $replace, $input);
    }

    return $input;
}
```

With a test:

```
echo strip("Hello <strong>there</strong>, what's `<em>`up`</em>`?");
// Output: Hello there, what's <em>up</em>?
```

Comment: I didn't think to use `preg_match_all` - just checked it out and it looks perfect for this situation. And thanks for the full solution!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not ignore backticks that might be escaped with \ or another escape sequence.

Comment: @TedPhillips A minor regex update would solve that problem if it's a requirement :-)

Answer (score 1):

If your escape sequence is fixed as a `, you can do something much simpler than obfuscation (which Marty suggests in his comment, and which is one of my favorite techniques if I'm being perfectly honest). Even if you were to use obfuscation or a preg_replace, you would still need to account for escaped ticks.

Instead, you can do something like:

```
$strippeddown = array();
$breakdown = explode('`', $text);
$j = 1;

foreach ($breakdown AS $i => $gather)
{
    if ($j > 1)
    {
        $j--;
        unset($breakdown["$i"]);
        continue;
    }

    $j = 1;
    while (strrpos($gather, '\\') === 0 AND isset($breakdown[$i + $j]))
    {
        $gather = $breakdown[$i + $j];
        $breakdown["$i"] .= '`' . $gather;
        $j++;
    }
}

$breakdown = array_values($breakdown);

foreach ($breakdown AS $i => $gather)
{
   if (!$i OR !($i % 2))
   {
      $strippeddown[] = strip_tags($gather);
   }
   else
   {
      $strippeddown[] = $gather;
   }
}

$text = implode('`', $strippeddown);
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, although I can't use it on this occasion as I'm unsure if backticks will be escaped ever. My `$text` variable is coming from the front-end

Comment: Okay, I've modified the above for an example how to do it if some backticks might be escaped. Please keep in mind this code is untested; I just typed it above now.

Comment: If you are going to display the user input to an end user, you probably also want to escape the tags not stripped, with htmlspecialchars or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into htmlspecialchars. +1 from me